# Android app not showing any installs on Developer console

Tags: android, statistics, installation

I have recently developed an Android app that i publish ad i do not see any current installs on my Developer console list.
I already installed on 2 devices. The application is free and i have also a paid version.I already have 3 reviews but no installs are showing...?!

```
play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=iappz.universalconverterfree
```

What settings do i still need to do? Is it mandatory to add/set up Google Analytics to track this?

I was under the impression that this is already build-in and a basic install statistics will be already available...

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How long ago did you release the app? Most of the statistics are usually a few days behind (latest stats I see on my apps are for the 23rd) so you may just need to wait a few days.

Answer (score 5):

The statistics related to the number of installs on the Google Play Console take some time to update. It not like that you install an application and suddenly it will update the console. It will take some time.